# How do I programmatically assign an id such as 'android:id/tabcontent''?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm looking for the Java equivalent to the XML assignment for assignments such as 'android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"'.

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setId(android.R.id.tabcontent)
```